# Check and increment the count on another sheet based on the data in this sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets in a workbook. I want to find the input given in one sheet and increment the count in another sheet. For eg, I am having nearly 25 questions and the answers to the questions would be Yes / No / n/a. I have kept a drop down input selector for these three options. After the 25 questions have been answered with either of these three options, at the click of submit button, I want the count of number of yes, no and N/As. For eg. 9 N/As, 10 Yes and 6 No.

The point is, I am planning to use the Sheet 1 as a form and Sheet 2 as the accumulation of results. So it needs to check the previous counts of Yes/No/N/As and increment the count.

The code I have tried at this point is as follows,

```
Sub Button3_Click()
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet

    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table 1")
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    sht2.Range("A2") = sht1.Range("D8")
    sht2.Range("B2") = sht1.Range("D9")
    sht2.Range("C2") = sht1.Range("D10")
End Sub
```

This macro is assigned to the submit button and the macro copies the data(Yes,No,N/As) to another sheet. I want to find the count on A2,B2,C2 and increment it with number of Yes,No and N/As.

Can anybody help me in doing this?

Comment: What values are in D8,D9,D10 on Sheet "Table 1"?

Comment: @ScottCraner For the moment I have given Yes, No and N/A in D8,D9, D10. The entire D column from D8 - D50 would be getting an answer of either Yes, No or N/A. I want to find out the count of those answers and add it to the previous value of A2,B2,C2 in sheet 2.

Comment: Ah, then use `sht2.Range("A2").value = sht2.Range("A2").value + worksheetFunction.countif(sht1.Range("B1:B25"),"=" & sht1.Range("D8").value)` You will change the range "B1:B2" to the range of the answers given by person filled out, where the dropdowns are.

Comment: @ScottCraner I am not able to understand this code properly. I want to check whther the answer given in D8:D30 is  yes ,no or N/a and correspondingly increment A2,B2 or C2 based on the answers given in D8:D30. The code which you gave does that?

Comment: No I misunderstood the formula for A2 would be `sht2.Range("A2").value = sht2.Range("A2").value + worksheetFunction.countif(sht1.Range("D8:D50"),"Yes")`

Comment: You can interpolate that for the "No"  and "N/A" questions in the B2 and C2 cells

Comment: @Scott Craner Thanks a lot it works. Can you put that as an answer? I can accept it?

Comment: I am glad I could help.  No need for an formal answer.  Enjoy.

Comment: Stay classy @ScottCraner

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two sheets in your workbook labeled "Table 1" and "Sheet1".

Assuming `"Table 1"` cell `D8` contains the number of `Yes`'s (probably computed by a `COUNTIF` or `COUNTIFS`), and similarly `D9` contains Number of `No`s and and `D10` contains the number of `N/A`s.

Your code works, but you seem to mention that you want to increment.

If so, you probably want

```
sht2.Range("A2") = sht2.Range("A2") + sht1.Range("D8")
sht2.Range("B2") = sht2.Range("B2") + sht1.Range("D9")
sht2.Range("C2") = sht2.Range("C2") + sht1.Range("D10")
```

---

If all you want is the total numbers of `Yes`, `No`, `N/A` in the 25 questions, then there is no need for a macro. Assuming that the answers to the 25 questions are in cells `D8` to `D32`, on the other sheet you would write:

Cell `A1`:  `Yes`
Cell `A2`:  `No`
Cell `A3`:  `N/A`

Cell `B1`:  `=COUNTIFS('Table 1'!$D$8:$D$32,A1)`

You could now copy the formula from B1 to B2 and B3, and they would all work.

Comment: I want to check the answer whether it is Yes, No or N/A and based on the answer I want to increament A2,B2 and C2 respectively. The code which u suggest increments it irrespective of the answer

Comment: Not enough space to answer in the comment, but it appears that you simply want a total of the counts, in which case you don't need VBA. Just use an excel formula. I have added this to my answer above.